# C# .NET Framework 3.5 alert message on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-10, .net-3.5

Currently, I'm developing an application in C # WPF in Visual Studio 2015. When I'm opening this application on Windows 10 where isn't installed `NET framework 3.5`.

I see the alert message with suggesting to install `NET framework 3.5` or to continue installation with compatibility issues. Could anybody advise please how is possible to disable this message on the application side for starting the application in normal mode on all PC with Windows 10?

[Alert message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC6Vu.png)

Comment: Why would you like to suppress the message which is asking for the framework dependency to be installed on the machine?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could update your post to include a screenshot of the actual message, and also that same message in textual form (so we can Google for it).

Comment: The alert is generated by Windows. I don't think it's possible to do a "work-around" in your software, unless you want to change the computer configuration (like regedit).

Comment: Because it can scare off users of the application. Image uploaded.

Comment: Either install .NET Framework 3.5 or change the target framework of your application to a newer version of  the .NET Framework and recompile it.

Comment: Newer version of the .NET Framework (4.0) doesn't works on Windows 7 where is installed .NET Framework 3.5. I need Win 7, Win 8,1 and Win 10.

Comment: @markus.shmidt Where did you get that idea from? 4.7.2 can be downloaded and installed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-7 .

Comment: Maybe I've described my problem incorrectly. I'll try to explain it in another way. For me is important to launch my C# WPF application on all windows version (starting with windows 7) without any difficultes for user. It can be 3.5, 4, 4.5 .NET Framework, I can compile my application in any of them

Comment: There is no "normal mode". Your application requires installed .Net 3.5 in order to run. If you even found some way to suppress that message and run your application, it will crash immediately since, guess what? - there is no .Net 3.5 installed. The system is so kind that instead of letting your application crash on start, it warns the user that they need to install the framework first.

Comment: Have you considered changing your install program so that it also includes the .NET Framework install?

Comment: It is common sense to ship an installer other than raw executable (unless you really have to). The typical tasks of the installer to validate the environment, install dependencies (such as .NET Framework) if needed, and then create shortcuts of your program for the users to use. Thus, merely discuss the raw executable is less meaningful, and also duplicate to existing threads.

Answer (score -1):

You shoud do upgrate ---> 4.5 framework.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You should consider expanding your answer motivating why he should upgrade framework and how to do it.